# C++ Graph class with multiple property maps (edit)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, graph

I wrote an improvement from my previous graph class: [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277898/c-graph-class-undirected-directed-weighted-unweighted-adj-list-adj-mat)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <concepts>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>


namespace frozenca {

template <typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept Descriptor = std::is_default_constructible_v<T> && std::is_assignable_v<T &, T> &&
    std::equality_comparable<T>;

template <typename Derived> struct EdgePropertyTag {};

struct EdgeWeightTag : public EdgePropertyTag<EdgeWeightTag> {};

EdgeWeightTag e_w;

template <typename Derived> struct VertexPropertyTag {};

struct VertexDistanceTag : public VertexPropertyTag<VertexDistanceTag> {};

VertexDistanceTag v_dist;

template <typename Derived> struct EmptyProperty {
  void operator()() const noexcept {
    // do nothing
  }
};

template <Descriptor VertexType, typename Traits, typename Properties>
class Graph : public Traits::template Impl<VertexType>,
              public Properties::template Impl<VertexType> {
public:
  using TraitBase = Traits::template Impl<VertexType>;

  using TraitBase::add_edge;
  using TraitBase::add_vertex;
  using TraitBase::adj;
  using TraitBase::has_edge;
  using TraitBase::has_vertex;
  using TraitBase::vertices;
};

template <Descriptor Vertex, typename Derived> struct AdjListTraits {
  using vertex_type = Vertex;
  using vertices_type = std::unordered_set<vertex_type>;
  using vertex_iterator_type = vertices_type::iterator;

  using edge_type = std::pair<vertex_type, vertex_type>;
  using adj_list_type = std::list<edge_type>;
  using edges_type = std::list<adj_list_type>;
  using edge_iterator_type = adj_list_type::iterator;
  using const_edge_iterator_type = adj_list_type::const_iterator;
  using out_edges_type =
      std::unordered_map<vertex_type, typename edges_type::iterator>;

  vertices_type vertices_;
  edges_type edges_;
  out_edges_type out_edges_;

  const auto &vertices() const noexcept { return vertices_; }

  void add_vertex(const vertex_type &vertex) {
    vertices_.insert(vertex);
    if (!out_edges_.contains(vertex)) {
      edges_.emplace_front();
      out_edges_.emplace(vertex, edges_.begin());
    }
  }

  bool has_vertex(const vertex_type &vertex) const {
    return vertices_.contains(vertex);
  }

  std::ranges::subrange<edge_iterator_type, edge_iterator_type>
  adj(const vertex_type &vertex) {
    return *out_edges_.at(vertex);
  }

  std::ranges::subrange<const_edge_iterator_type, const_edge_iterator_type>
  adj(const vertex_type &vertex) const {
    return *out_edges_.at(vertex);
  }

  bool has_edge(const edge_type &edge) const {
    auto edge_range = adj(edge.first);
    return std::ranges::find(edge_range, edge) != edge_range.end();
  }

  void add_edge(const vertex_type &src, const vertex_type &dst) {
    out_edges_[src]->emplace_front(src, dst);
  }
};

struct AdjListTraitTag {
  template <Descriptor VertexType, typename Derived>
  using Trait = AdjListTraits<VertexType, Derived>;
};

template <Descriptor VertexType, bool Directed, typename ContainerTraitTag>
struct GraphTraitsImpl
    : public ContainerTraitTag::template Trait<
          VertexType,
          GraphTraitsImpl<VertexType, Directed, ContainerTraitTag>> {
  using vertex_type = VertexType;
  using Base = ContainerTraitTag::template Trait<
      VertexType, GraphTraitsImpl<VertexType, Directed, ContainerTraitTag>>;
  static constexpr bool directed_ = Directed;

  using Base::add_vertex;
  using Base::adj;
  using Base::has_edge;
  using Base::has_vertex;
  using Base::vertices;

  void add_edge(const vertex_type &src, const vertex_type &dst) {
    add_vertex(src);
    add_vertex(dst);
    Base::add_edge(src, dst);
    if constexpr (!directed_) {
      Base::add_edge(dst, src);
    }
  }
};

template <bool Directed, typename ContainerTraitTag> struct GraphTraits {
  template <Descriptor VertexType>
  using Impl = GraphTraitsImpl<VertexType, Directed, ContainerTraitTag>;
};

template <typename ContainerTraitTag>
using DiGraphTraits = GraphTraits<true, ContainerTraitTag>;

template <Descriptor VertexType, typename... BaseProperties>
struct GraphProperties : public BaseProperties::template Impl<VertexType>... {
  using BaseProperties::template Impl<VertexType>::operator()...;
};

template <Arithmetic WeightType, typename EdgeType> struct EdgeWeightImpl {
  WeightType &operator()(EdgeWeightTag, const EdgeType &edge) {
    return weights_[edge];
  }
  const WeightType &operator()(EdgeWeightTag, const EdgeType &edge) const {
    return weights_.at(edge);
  }

  std::map<EdgeType, WeightType> weights_;
};

template <Arithmetic WeightType> struct EdgeWeightProperty {
  template <Descriptor VertexType>
  using Impl = EdgeWeightImpl<WeightType, std::pair<VertexType, VertexType>>;
};

template <Arithmetic DistanceType, Descriptor VertexType>
struct VertexDistanceImpl {

  DistanceType &operator()(VertexDistanceTag, const VertexType &vertex) {
    return distances_[vertex];
  }
  const DistanceType &operator()(VertexDistanceTag,
                                 const VertexType &vertex) const {
    return distances_.at(vertex);
  }

  std::unordered_map<VertexType, DistanceType> distances_;
};

template <Arithmetic DistanceType> struct VertexDistanceProperty {
  template <Descriptor VertexType>
  using Impl = VertexDistanceImpl<DistanceType, VertexType>;
};

template <Arithmetic DistType> struct DijkstraProperties {
  template <Descriptor VertexType>
  using Impl = GraphProperties<VertexType, VertexDistanceProperty<DistType>,
                               EdgeWeightProperty<DistType>>;
};

} // namespace frozenca
```

Test code(Dijkstra's algorithm):

```
#include <graph.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>


namespace fc = frozenca;

using DijkstraGraph = fc::Graph<int, fc::DiGraphTraits<fc::AdjListTraitTag>, fc::DijkstraProperties<float>>;

std::pair<float, int> dijkstra(DijkstraGraph &g, int src) {
  auto min_dist_comp = [&g](int v1, int v2) {
    return g(fc::v_dist, v1) > g(fc::v_dist, v2);
  };

  constexpr auto INF = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

  std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(min_dist_comp)> q(min_dist_comp);
  for (auto vertex : g.vertices()) {
    g(fc::v_dist, vertex) = INF;
  }
  

  int min_dst = -1;
  float min_dist = INF;

  g(fc::v_dist, src) = 0;
  q.push(src);
  while (!q.empty()) {
    auto u = q.top();
    q.pop();

    for (auto [_, v] : g.adj(u)) {
      auto alt = g(fc::v_dist, u) + g(fc::e_w, {u, v});
      if (alt < g(fc::v_dist, v) && g(fc::v_dist, u) != INF) {
        g(fc::v_dist, v) = alt;
        min_dst = v;
        min_dist = std::min(min_dist, alt);
      }
    }
  }
  return {min_dist, min_dst};
}

int main() {
  DijkstraGraph g;

  g.add_edge(0, 2);
  g.add_edge(1, 3);
  g.add_edge(1, 4);
  g.add_edge(2, 1);
  g.add_edge(2, 3);
  g.add_edge(3, 4);
  g.add_edge(4, 0);
  g.add_edge(4, 1);

  g(fc::e_w, {0, 2}) = 1;
  g(fc::e_w, {1, 3}) = 1;
  g(fc::e_w, {1, 4}) = 2;
  g(fc::e_w, {2, 1}) = 7;
  g(fc::e_w, {2, 3}) = 3;
  g(fc::e_w, {3, 4}) = 1;
  g(fc::e_w, {4, 0}) = 1;
  g(fc::e_w, {4, 1}) = 1;

  auto [dist, dst] = dijkstra(g, 0);
  std::cout << "Shortest distance: " << dist << " with destination " << dst << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
Shortest distance: 1 with destination 2
```

I'm not sure I can handle this TMP monstrosity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Miscellaneous issues

- You can use `[]` instead of `.at()` in the non-`const` `adj()`.
- `#include <vector>` is not necessary.
- `#include <graph.h>` is dangerous, use `"graph.h"` instead, otherwise you risk a `graph.h` that's in the system header search path from being found before your local header file.

## Store adjacency lists directly in `out_edges_`

I don't see why you have a `std::list` storing adjacency lists, and a `std::unordered_map` that maps vertices to iterators into that `std::list`. Why not store the adjacency lists directly in the `std::unordered_map`? This simplifies the code.

## Use of `std::list`

A `std::list` has the problem that looking up things is slow. Consider `has_edge()`, which has \$O(V)\$ complexity because it has to do a linear search.

## Use of `std::map`

Nothing in `EdgeWeightImpl` depends on `weights_` being sorted. So ideally, you would use a `std::unordered_map` instead. Of course, the issue is that there is no overload for `std::hash` for `EdgeType`. However, you could make one yourself, or pass a custom hash function to the constructor of `weights_` if you make it a `std::unordered_map`.

## Make things `private` where appropriate

If you add accessor functions to a `struct` or `class` to access its member variables, I expect those member variables to be `private`. Even if some of your `struct`s are only used internally, it is good practice to use `public`/`protected`/`private` to reduce bugs in your own code.

## Missing `typename`?

C++20 is supposed to reduce the need for writing `typename`. I am not a language lawyer, so I won't comment on whether your code is techinally correct, however Clang seems to think `typename` is missing in some of your `using` declarations. So from a practical standpoint, add `typename` whenever there is a dependent type to avoid compiler issues.

## Naming things

There are a few things I would do differently regarding naming. First, adding `Type` to template parameter names seems unnecessary; you already make them start with a capital so they are easily distinguished from the (member) variables. I think it just adds noise.

Properties vs traits: these words mean very similar things. Without reading the code, I wouldn't know where to put what if I had to create a custom trait and a custom property class.

`DijkstraProperties` is misnamed and hints at possible issues. First, there might be other algorithms that work on a graph that has edge weights and vertex distances. You might also want to run multiple algorithms on a given graph. Naming a graph type after one of the possible algorithms you could use on it doesn't seem like a good idea. Furthermore, storing information in a graph that is only used while a given algorithm runs on it wastes memory when you are not running that algorithm, and also prevents you from running that algorithm on a `const` graph. Of course, if you run Dijkstra's a lot and it's the fastest way to do it, it is fine, but I wouldn't expect this from such a generic graph library.

## Usability

> I'm not sure I can handle this TMP monstrosity...

It's just lots of templates, I don't see any real metaprogramming here. But yes, it's a bit of a monstrosity. And while the end-user doesn't have to look at the implementation, they still have to write things like this:

```
using DijkstraGraph = fc::Graph<int, fc::DiGraphTraits<fc::AdjListTraitTag>, fc::DijkstraProperties<float>>;
```

Which doesn't look particularly appealing. Again, I don't think it's clear what the distinction between the `Trait` and `Property` is, so I'd much rather see `Graph` having just one template parameter that contains all the information necessary. That type will then be more complicated of course, but with some real template meta-programming you can have it deduce many of the traits and properties instead of having to explicitly specify them.

Comment: Thanks as always, for minor things, ```has_edge()``` is at most ```O(V)``` because it scans the edge from only out edges from the source vertex of the edge. For encapsulation, I changed inheritance of ```Graph``` from ```Traits``` and ```Properties``` from ```public``` to ```private``` inheritance. For ```typename```, Clang still doesn't support P0634R3 as of clang15 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: I'm considering extracting out ```Properties``` from ```Graph```, IMO ```Graph``` should only hold the references to ```Properties``` only if necessary, and users have to be free to put on and off ```Properties```, they shouldn't restrict ```Graph```'s type system. Binding ```Properties``` to ```Graph```'s type system was an idea inspired from Boost.Graph, but after coding, I thought that design decision was a big mistake

Comment: Oops, it's indeed \$O(V)\$. `private` inheritance is already good, but you could also make the member variables of `AdjListTraits` `private` for example, and it will still compile. As for Boost Graph, the first release was apparently in 2000, so they had to work with C++98. I guess a lot of design decisions came from the limitations of the language at that time.

Comment: I separated ```Properties``` from ```Graph```'s type system now, ```Graph``` now holds a member variable ```std::map<GraphPropertyTag, std::unique_ptr<PropertyMap>>```. ```GraphPropertyTag``` is now just a ```enum class```, all property maps inherit ```PropertyMap```

Comment: There are now just three bases classes for ```PropertyMap```: ```VertexProperty```, ```EdgeProperty``` and ```GraphProperty```, all three inherit ```PropertyMap```, and all of them are parametrized