# C++ Refactored graph again, separated property maps from Graph type

Tags: c++, design-patterns, graph

This is yet another improvement from my graph class - [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278432/c-graph-class-with-multiple-property-maps-edit)

Now property maps are no longer parts of `Graph` type, they are just stored in a member variable.

This seems much more reasonable for me! It is wise to combine dynamic polymorphism and static polymorphism appropriately.

```
#include "GraphProperties.h"
#include <memory>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept GraphConcept = T::is_graph_;

template <typename T>
concept DiGraphConcept = GraphConcept<T> && T::directed_;


template <Descriptor VertexType, typename Traits>
class Graph : private Traits::template Impl<VertexType> {
public:
  using TraitBase = Traits::template Impl<VertexType>;
  using vertex_type = TraitBase::vertex_type;
  using edge_type = TraitBase::edge_type;
  static constexpr bool directed_ = TraitBase::directed_;
  static constexpr bool is_graph_ = true;

  Graph() : TraitBase() {}

  void add_vertex(const vertex_type &v) { TraitBase::add_vertex(v); }

  void add_edge(const vertex_type &src, const vertex_type &dst) {
    TraitBase::add_edge(src, dst);
  }

  auto adj(const vertex_type &src) { return TraitBase::adj(src); }

  auto adj(const vertex_type &src) const { return TraitBase::adj(src); }

  const auto &vertices() const noexcept { return TraitBase::vertices(); }

  [[nodiscard]] auto size() const noexcept {
    return TraitBase::vertices().size();
  }

  const auto &edges() const noexcept { return TraitBase::edges(); }

  const auto &out_edges() const noexcept { return TraitBase::out_edges(); }

  bool has_vertex(const vertex_type &src) const noexcept {
    return TraitBase::has_vertex(src);
  }

  bool has_edge(const edge_type &edge) const noexcept {
    return TraitBase::has_edge(edge);
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type> &
  add_vertex_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    properties_.emplace(
        tag, std::make_unique<VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type>>());
    return get_vertex_property<PropertyType>(tag);
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type> &
  add_edge_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    properties_.emplace(tag,
                        std::make_unique<EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type>>());
    return get_edge_property<PropertyType>(tag);
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  GraphProperty<PropertyType> &add_graph_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    properties_.emplace(tag, std::make_unique<GraphProperty<PropertyType>>());
    return get_graph_property<PropertyType>(tag);
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type> &
  get_vertex_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    return dynamic_cast<VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type> &>(
        *properties_.at(tag));
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  const VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type> &
  get_vertex_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) const {
    return dynamic_cast<const VertexProperty<PropertyType, vertex_type> &>(
        *properties_.at(tag));
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type> &
  get_edge_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    return dynamic_cast<EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type> &>(
        *properties_.at(tag));
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  const EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type> &
  get_edge_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) const {
    return dynamic_cast<const EdgeProperty<PropertyType, edge_type> &>(
        *properties_.at(tag));
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  GraphProperty<PropertyType> &get_graph_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) {
    return dynamic_cast<GraphProperty<PropertyType> &>(*properties_.at(tag));
  }

  template <typename PropertyType>
  const GraphProperty<PropertyType> &
  get_graph_property(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) const {
    return dynamic_cast<const GraphProperty<PropertyType> &>(
        *properties_.at(tag));
  }

private:
  std::unordered_map<GraphPropertyTag, std::unique_ptr<Property>> properties_;
};

// omit AdjList Traits
```

GraphProperties.h

```
#include <bit>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>



enum class GraphPropertyTag : std::int32_t {
  VertexDistance,
  VertexVisited,
  VertexRank,
  VertexSize,
  VertexParent,
  VertexLink,
  EdgeWeight,
  GraphTopSort,
};

template<> struct std::hash<GraphPropertyTag> {
  std::size_t operator()(const GraphPropertyTag &tag) const {
    return std::hash<std::uint32_t>{}(std::bit_cast<std::uint32_t>(tag));
  }
};

struct Property {
  virtual ~Property() {}
};

enum class VisitMark {
  Unvisited,
  Visiting,
  Visited
};

template <typename PropertyType, Descriptor VertexType>
struct VertexProperty final : public Property {

  static constexpr bool int_vertex_ = std::is_integral_v<VertexType>;

  PropertyType &operator()(const VertexType &vertex) {
    if constexpr (int_vertex_) {
      if (vertex >= std::ssize(vertex_properties_)) {
        vertex_properties_.resize(vertex + 1);
      }
    }
    return vertex_properties_[vertex];
  }
  const PropertyType &operator()(const VertexType &vertex) const {
    return vertex_properties_.at(vertex);
  }

private:
  std::conditional_t<int_vertex_, std::vector<PropertyType>,
                std::unordered_map<VertexType, PropertyType>>
      vertex_properties_;
};

template <typename PropertyType, typename EdgeType>
struct EdgeProperty final : public Property {
  PropertyType &operator()(const EdgeType &edge) {
    return edge_properties_[edge];
  }
  const PropertyType &operator()(const EdgeType &edge) const {
    return edge_properties_.at(edge);
  }

private:
  std::unordered_map<EdgeType, PropertyType, std::hash<EdgeType>> edge_properties_;
};

template <typename PropertyType>
struct GraphProperty final : public Property {
  PropertyType& operator()() {
    return graph_property_;
  }

  const PropertyType& operator()() const {
    return graph_property_;
  }
private:
  PropertyType graph_property_;
};
```

Topological sort example

```
template <DiGraphConcept DiGraphType>
bool topological_sort_helper(
    DiGraphType &g,
    VertexProperty<VisitMark, typename DiGraphType::vertex_type> &visited,
    GraphProperty<std::list<typename DiGraphType::vertex_type>> &top_sort,
    const typename DiGraphType::vertex_type &vertex) {
  visited(vertex) = VisitMark::Visiting;

  for (const auto &[_, dst] : g.adj(vertex)) {
    auto status = visited(dst);
    if (status == VisitMark::Unvisited) {
      if (!topological_sort_helper(g, visited, top_sort, dst)) {
        top_sort().clear();
        return false;
      }
    } else if (status == VisitMark::Visiting) {
      std::cerr << "Not a DAG, can't topological sort\n";
      top_sort().clear();
      return false;
    }
  }
  visited(vertex) = VisitMark::Visited;
  top_sort().push_back(vertex);
  return true;
}

template <DiGraphConcept DiGraphType> void topological_sort(DiGraphType &g) {
  using vertex_type = DiGraphType::vertex_type;

  auto &visited =
      g.add_vertex_property<VisitMark>(GraphPropertyTag::VertexVisited);
  auto &top_sort =
      g.add_graph_property<std::list<vertex_type>>(GraphPropertyTag::GraphTopSort);

  for (const auto &vertex : g.vertices()) {
    if (visited(vertex) == VisitMark::Unvisited) {
      topological_sort_helper(g, visited, top_sort, vertex);
    }
  }
}
```

Union Find example

````
template <Descriptor V>
void make_set(VertexProperty<V, V> &parent, VertexProperty<int, V> &rank,
              VertexProperty<V, V> &link, const V &vertex) {
  parent(vertex) = vertex;
  rank(vertex) = 0;
  link(vertex) = vertex;
}

template <Descriptor V>
V find_set(UndirGraph<V> &g, VertexProperty<V, V> &parent, const V &v) {
  if (parent(v) != v) {
    parent(v) = find_set(g, parent, parent(v));
  }
  return parent(v);
}

template <Descriptor V>
void link_by_size(VertexProperty<V, V> &parent, VertexProperty<int, V> &rank,
                  VertexProperty<V, V> &link, const V &x, const V &y) {
  auto temp = link(y);
  link(y) = link(x);
  link(x) = temp;
  if (rank(x) > rank(y)) {
    parent(y) = x;
  } else {
    parent(x) = y;
    if (rank(x) == rank(y)) {
      rank(y) += rank(x);
    }
  }
}

template <Descriptor V> void union_find_by_size(UndirGraph<V> &g) {
  auto &parent = g.add_vertex_property<V>(GraphPropertyTag::VertexParent);
  auto &rank = g.add_vertex_property<int>(GraphPropertyTag::VertexRank);
  auto &link = g.add_vertex_property<V>(GraphPropertyTag::VertexLink);
  for (const auto &vertex : g.vertices()) {
    make_set(parent, rank, link, vertex);
  }

  for (const auto &v : g.vertices()) {
    for (const auto &[_, u] : g.adj(v)) {
      auto vr = find_set(g, parent, v);
      auto ur = find_set(g, parent, u);
      link_by_size(parent, rank, link, vr, ur);
    }
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly an interesting way to have a generic graph class that is dynamically extensible. It's very nice to be able to write code like `visited(vertex) = ...`.

## Use more `[[nodiscard]]`

I see you use `[[nodiscard]]` for `size()`, but there are many more functions where `[[nodiscard]]` would be appropriate.

## No need to overload `std::hash` for enums

[`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) already has specializations for all possible enum types, you don't need to specialize it for `GraphPropertyTag`.

## Consider using `operator[]` instead of `operator()` for properties

Since a graph is like a container, I think it feels more natural to use bracket notation to access its elements. Since everything has to be accessed via properties, I would add `operator[]` member functions to them instead of `operator()`.

Comment: Yup, my friend bashed me for using `operator()` instead of `operator[]`, because not only it confuses notational convention, but also declaring `operator()` makes it a callable object. Current code is like this: https://github.com/frozenca/CLRS/blob/main/core/graph_algorithms.h#L131-#L144